# Changing tabs via buttons, array index out of bounds?

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

I have a JTabPanel with three tabs, two of which start disabled. I want enable them when they have been given content (otherwise some of the fields and boxes are blank and/or meaningless).

It seems the only way to set whether a tab is enabled or disabled is to pass `setEnabledAt` an int for the tab index and the boolean. The only way I can find to pass the index of a tab to something is to use `indexOfTabComponent` and pass in the panel to swap to....This seems horrible, and doesn't work. I'm getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1` when I try and swap to the tab at index 1.

#### Is there a better way than this?

```
public void swapView(JPanel paneToSelect) {
    myContainerPane.getMyPaneTab().setSelectedComponent(paneToSelect);
    myContainerPane.getMyPaneTab().setEnabledAt(myContainerPane.getMyPaneTab().indexOfTabComponent(paneToSelect), true);
}
```

The only solution I can think of is to add 2 to the index number...but it feels there should be a better way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct code to use is:

```
public void swapView(JPanel paneToSelect) {
    int index = myContainerPane.getMyPaneTab().indexOfComponent(paneToSelect);
    myContainerPane.getMyPaneTab().setSelectedIndex(index);
    myContainerPane.getMyPaneTab().setEnabledAt(index, true);
}
```

The difference being is that, for whatever reason *`indexOf`*`Tab`*`Component`*, does not work with my set up.

Comment: `indexOfTabComponent` finds the index of the `Component` been used to render the actual "Tab" - It's the mechanism used to provide customisation to the actual "Tab" part of the component.  `indexOfComponent` returns the tab index where the specified `Component` is been displayed in - I mix these up all the time.

Comment: Why would a component rendering a tab even have an index....nm, at least it works.

Comment: It's the same association with the component been used as the tabs view. Each tab can have an optional tab "renderer" & a view. They are both manged by JTabbedPane via there indices.

Answer (score 1):

ordering started from zero :-)

[image]       ,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,  [image]

for example :-)

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TabbedPane {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public TabbedPane() {
        JPanel jp = new JPanel();
        jp.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        final JTabbedPane tb = new JTabbedPane();
        //tb.setUI(new CustomTabbedPaneUI());
        JButton btn = new JButton("push me !!!");
        btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                tb.setEnabledAt(1, true);
                tb.setEnabledAt(2, true);
                tb.setEnabledAt(3, true);
                tb.setEnabledAt(4, true);
            }
        });
        JPanel pnl = new JPanel();
        pnl.add(btn);
        tb.add("Tab1", pnl);
        tb.add("Tab2", new JTextArea(10, 20));
        tb.add("Tab3", new JTextArea(10, 20));
        tb.add("Tab4", new JTextArea(10, 20));
        tb.add("Tab5", new JTextArea(10, 20));
        jp.add(tb, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        tb.setEnabledAt(1, false);
        tb.setEnabledAt(2, false);
        tb.setEnabledAt(3, false);
        tb.setEnabledAt(4, false);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(jp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            for (UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception system) {
            system.printStackTrace();
        }
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TabbedPane tP = new TabbedPane();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem I (personally) have with this approach is it assumes that the tab order/indices are well known, this is not always the case. The same goes with using the tab names. IMHO

Comment: My problem with this is that I'm not doing anything like the example you give. @MadProgrammer is right, I don't know the name or index of the tab. This isn't very helpful.

Comment: This isn't very helpful. sorry :-) :-) no battery included, your question and answer have got the same issue ...,

Answer (score 1):

Once selected, you coud use `getSelectedIndex` instead.

Or you could use the tabs title, but that would mean you know it & ties you into the naming.

```
int index = myContainerPane.getMyPaneTab().indexOfTabComponent(paneToSelect);
myContainerPane.getMyPaneTab().setSelectedIndex(index);
myContainerPane.getMyPaneTab().setEnabledAt(index, true);
```

The only other choice that comes to mind is extending the base class & implementing your methods to achieve the ensured results

Comment: I'm still getting an Array Index Out of Bounds exception with this code, even if I use `myContainerPane.getMyPaneTab().getSelectedIndex()` as my index.

Comment: +1 for suggestingto extend the base class, but a) that seems unecessary, and b) I'm not even sure hwo to get the expected result.

Comment: It turns out for some reaosn there is a method `indexOfTabComponent` and `indexOfComponent` and only one works.

Comment: `indexOfTabComponent` returns the Component been used to represent the tab.  It's used to allow customisation of the Tabs them selves.  So obvious :P.  The suggestion of extending the base class is to implement the missing the functionality, it would only look up the index and call the appropriate method on your behalf, it's about making our lives easier.  I was going to suggest making a utility class `MyAwesomeUtilities.setTabEnabled(JTabbedPane, Component, boolean)` instead of extending

Comment: ps - I mix up those two method calls all the time :P

Comment: [`indexOfTabComponent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTabbedPane.html#indexOfTabComponent(java.awt.Component)) definitely returns an int...

Comment: Sorry, you're right, it returns the index of the tab that is using this `Component` to render it's "Tab" part of the component...I'm going to bed :P